# jquery, simple-inheritance and 'this'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, inheritance

so i'm trying to use javascript with 'simple inheritance' (as per http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/). to "simplify" things, my idea was to create objects and attach them to elements so i can operate on them;

```
var Pane = Class.extend({
    init: function( el ) {
        this.el = el; this.$el = $(el);
        return this;
    },

    do_something: function() {
        this.$el.html('doing something!');
        $.getJSON( '/somewhere.js', function(data){
            // write something to $el
        });
    }
});
```

and i would have some html like

```
<div id="my_div"></div>
<script>
    var p = new Pane( $('#my_div') )
    p.do_something()
</script>
```

unfortunately, within the ajax call, 'this' becomes the jquery object, rather than my Pane object so i can't update the $el / my_div (and also making my idea somewhat pointless). any ideas how i can access the object within the getJSON call?

Comment: Do you have to use inheritance? Maybe you would have to store a reference to each object called in a var somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a closure (copy `this` to other variable outside)

```
    ...
    do_something: function() {
        this.$el.html('doing something!');
        var that = this; //Copy 'this' to 'that'
        $.getJSON( '/somewhere.js', function(data){
            that.$el.html("..."); //use 'that' instead of 'this' here
        });
    }
```

Another way is to use jQuery `$.proxy` (which changes function context). Like this:

```
     ...
     do_something: function() {
         this.$el.html('doing something!');            
         $.getJSON( '/somewhere.js', $.proxy( function(data){  //Here we proxy
             this.$el.html("..."); //use 'this' normally
         }, this));  //Using 'this' as context
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just store the value of this in a variable within do_something, before the getJSON call:

var currentpane=this;

Comment: yep - that was exactly the solution! (i realised as soon as i hit submit, but wasn't allowed to answer my own question...) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with the inheritance thing, you could create a base class that is able to create callbacks that are bound to its instances like this:

```
var Bindable = Class.extend({
    bind: function( fn ) {
        var that = this;
        return function(){ return fn.apply( that, arguments ); };
    }
}
```

Now you can extend this class and use its bind method to create callbacks

```
// extend Bindable
var Pane = Bindable.extend({
    init: function( el ) {
        this.el = el; this.$el = $(el);
        // don't return this, it's incorrect;
        //return this;
    },

    handleData: function( data ) {
        // grab an imaginary key from the data for demo purposes
        var stuff = data.key;
        this.$el.html( stuff );
    },

    do_something: function() {
        this.$el.html('doing something!');
        $.getJSON( '/somewhere.js', this.bind( this.handleData ) );
    }
});
```